# Installing pure-python package as subpackage of another platform-dependent package

Tags: python, centos, rpm, distutils, setup.py

I have a pure-python package `B` and a platform-dependent package `A` (i.e. `A` contains C-extension module). I wish to install `B` as a subpackage of `A`, and the expected hierarchy is like,

```
<python-libdir>/site-packages/
    + <A>
        + __init__.py
        + _<A>.so
        + <B>
            + __init__.py
            + _<B>.py
```

Due to licensing and other concerns, I need to place `A` and `B` in separate projects, and create separate `distutils` scripts (aka. `setup.py`) for each of them.

Problem is that `A` is platform-dependent. And when I (rpm-)package `<A>` on a CentOS / RHEL (x86_64) system (i.e., via `$ python setup.py bdist_rpm`), it installs to,

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/<A>
```

Whereas `B` is a pure-python package, and, by default, its content goes to,

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/<A>/<B>
```

I tried the `--force-arch` option when building rpm package for `<B>`, i.e.,

```
$ python setupB.py bdist_rpm --force-arch x86_64
```

This generates the rpm-package of `B` with `x86_64` in its filename (instead of `noarch`), but it still installs `<B>` to `/usr/lib/...`, not the desired `/usr/lib64/...`.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to configure `<B>` (i.e. maybe setting some arguments in `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`), such that it installs to platform-dependent libdir (i.e. `/usr/lib64/...`)?

EDIT: I am aware of the `--install-purelib` option of the `install` command, i.e.,

```
$ python setupB.py install --install-purelib=/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

It does achieves the desired package hierarchy. But there does not seem to be an equivalent option for the `bdist_rpm` command of `distutils`.

Could there be a way to specify this `--install-purelib` option within `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`?

Comment: I think you can pass a  `--prefix` switch as well. Read through the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/install/

Comment: @Blender, I believe `--prefix` only specifies whether the package goes to `/usr` or `/usr/local`, and it has no effect on `libdir`.

Comment: This does not help you any way, but doing python setup.py install to system-wide folders is not recommended: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/ I would suggest to create an isolated environment and startup script which manually builds the hierarchy needed to execute the application with your libraries.